# Maintaining focus of PaperJS drag item (Sketch)

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, paperjs

I have a function `closestPointData` to determine the closest point of a line, highlight that point by showing a red dot and to determine which point needs to be dragged.

I'm having a problem with the tolerance, when I drag too fast, the mouse "drops" the point.

How can I ensure I don't exceed the tolerance of 30px

#### See [Sketch](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#V/0.12.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) for working version

```
line = new Path.Line([90, 90], [250, 250]);
line.strokeColor = 'black';
line.strokeWidth = 3;

var redDot = new Path.Circle({
  center: view.center,
  radius: 3,
  fillColor: 'transparent',
  position: [90, 90]
});

function onMouseDrag(e) {
  var cpd = closestPointData(e);
  if (cpd.closestDistance < 30) {
    line.segments[cpd.closestPointIndex].point = e.point;
    redDot.position = cpd.usePoint;
  }
}


function onMouseMove(e) {
  var cpd = closestPointData(e);
  if (cpd.closestDistance < 30) {
    redDot.position = cpd.usePoint;
    redDot.fillColor = 'red';
  }else{
    redDot.fillColor = 'transparent';
  }
}

// Determine which of the line segment points is closest to the mouse pointer
function closestPointData(e) {
  var closestPointIndex = null;
  var closestDistance = Infinity;
  var usePoint; // segment point coordinates
  // console.log(line.segments);
  
  // get point from each end of segment
  for (var i = 0; i < line.segments.length; i++) {
    var pointAt = line.getPointAt(line.segments[i]);
    var distance = e.point.getDistance(pointAt);
    
    // Qualify shortest distance
    if (distance < closestDistance) {
      closestDistance = distance;
      closestPointIndex = i;
      usePoint = pointAt;
    }
  }
  return {
    closestPointIndex: closestPointIndex,
    closestDistance: closestDistance,
    usePoint: usePoint
  };
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, the `onMouseDrag` handler is usefull only when there is no `onMouseMove`, otherwise, it gets a bit confusing.
I would do it this [way](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#V/0.12.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).

```js
// Set target size.
const MIN_DISTANCE = 30;

// Create items.
const path = new Path.Line({
    from: view.center,
    to: view.center + 150,
    strokeColor: 'black',
    strokeWidth: 2,
});
const dot = new Path.Circle({
    center: view.center,
    radius: 5,
    fillColor: 'transparent',
});

// Create state variables.
// This will store the active path point.
let activePoint;
// This will allow us to check if we are currently dragging or not.
let dragging = false;

function onMouseDown() {
    dragging = true;
}

function onMouseMove(event) {
    // If we are not currently dragging...
    if (!dragging) {
        // ...look for the closest path point...
        const closest = path.segments
            .map((it) => ({point: it.point, distance: it.point.getDistance(event.point)}))
            .sort((a, b) => a.distance - b.distance)
            .shift();
        // ...and if it is close enough...
        if (closest.distance <= MIN_DISTANCE) {
            // ...show the dot...
            dot.fillColor = 'red';
            dot.position = closest.point;
            // ...and store the active point.
            activePoint = closest.point;
        }
        // Otherwise...
        else {
            // ...hide the dot...
            dot.fillColor = 'transparent';
            // ...and store no active point.
            activePoint = null;
        }
    }
    // If we are dragging and there is an active point...
    else if (activePoint) {
        // ...move the dot...
        dot.position += event.delta;
        // ...and move the path point.
        activePoint.x = dot.position.x;
        activePoint.y = dot.position.y;
    }
}

function onMouseUp() {
    dragging = false;
}
```

Comment: Very nice and I appreciate the code improvements too. Much appreciated.